# making hyperlinks clickable in multiline fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, hyperlink, multiline

I have a requirement in SharePoint, in which I have a multi line field (with Plain text type) which stores description. In some of the list item the description contains urls. But in the page its showing as real text instead of links. I need to convert these url as clickable. Is there any option to do this. Please help me on this. All suggestions are appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

There is an way to achive this with the OOTB in SharePoint !
You just need to change a settings of your Field (of type Multiple lines of text) you need to change the type of text to : **Rich Text**

Comment: In other words, you advice the OP to change the type to Rich Text. This isn't "just a setting", it's an important change

Comment: Customer won't allow to change the type from as it is. This column contains confidential data.

Comment: The only difference between this 2 config, it's the type of data who are stored in the fields (you don't change the the Type of collumn, juste the type of data stored). The Plain text store the data as simple string, the rich text store data as HTML (so you can add Link, color ....).